# core-ktx 1.7.0 and Hilt

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gradle, dagger-hilt

I've just updated my project's `core-ktx` (`androidx.core:core-ktx`) version to `1.7.0`, and now I can't compile my project. In fact, at my PC everything works OK, but in Github Actions the build is broken.

At first I was getting this error:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':core:verifyReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.VerifyLibraryResourcesTask$Action
   > Android resource linking failed
     ERROR:/home/runner/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/cf34be3e77386540a828d329143911c7/transformed/core-1.7.0/res/values/values.xml:105:5-114:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found.
```

But updating to SDK `31` fixed this issue. Now I'm getting the following one:

```
> Task :core:hiltAggregateDepsDebugUnitTest
WARNING: [Processor] Library '/home/runner/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/fd6df19df5b3c35086ae117610be6db2/transformed/browser-1.0.0-api.jar' contains references to both AndroidX and old support library. This seems like the library is partially migrated. Jetifier will try to rewrite the library anyway.
 Example of androidX reference: 'androidx/browser/R$styleable'
 Example of support library reference: 'android/support/customtabs/ICustomTabsCallback$Stub$Proxy'
WARNING: [Processor] Library '/home/runner/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/fc7ccfb37357e9edd2e98ab346848a40/transformed/core-1.7.0-api.jar' contains references to both AndroidX and old support library. This seems like the library is partially migrated. Jetifier will try to rewrite the library anyway.
 Example of androidX reference: 'androidx/core/R$styleable'
 Example of support library reference: 'android/support/v4/app/INotificationSideChannel$Default'

> Task :core:javaPreCompileReleaseUnitTest
> Task :core:compileReleaseUnitTestJavaWithJavac NO-SOURCE
> Task :core:createFullJarRelease
/home/runner/work/Android/Android/core/build/generated/hilt/component_sources/debugUnitTest/com/***/.../core/shared/Hilt_App.java:20: error: cannot find symbol

      return DaggerApp_HiltComponents_SingletonC.builder()
> Task :core:hiltJavaCompileDebugUnitTest FAILED
             ^
  symbol: variable DaggerApp_HiltComponents_SingletonC
1 error


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':core:hiltJavaCompileDebugUnitTest'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

This is my `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
    id 'org.jetbrains.dokka'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31
    buildToolsVersion "31.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 31

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles "consumer-rules.pro"

        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
        compose true
    }

    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
    }
}

tasks.named("dokkaHtmlPartial") {
    dokkaSourceSets {
        configureEach {
            noAndroidSdkLink.set(false)
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.5.31'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.1.1'

    // Testing
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:4.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    // KotlinX Coroutines
    api 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.5.2'
    api 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.5.2'
    api 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.5.2'

    // Android Jetpack
    def jetpack_work_version = '2.7.0'
    api "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:$jetpack_work_version"
    api "androidx.work:work-gcm:$jetpack_work_version"
    androidTestApi "androidx.work:work-testing:$jetpack_work_version"
    api "androidx.startup:startup-runtime:1.1.0"

    // Jetpack compose
    api "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    api "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
    api "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:$compose_version"
    api "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    api "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-core:$compose_version"
    api "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:$compose_version"
    api "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:$compose_version"
    api "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-rxjava2:$compose_version"
    api 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.4.0'
    api 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.4.0'
    api 'androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.4.0-beta02'
    api 'com.google.accompanist:accompanist-appcompat-theme:0.20.1'
    androidTestApi "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"

    // Coil image loading
    api 'io.coil-kt:coil:1.4.0'
    api 'io.coil-kt:coil-compose:1.4.0'

    // Live Data
    api 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.0'

    // Google Play Core
    api 'com.google.android.play:core:1.10.2'
    api 'com.google.android.play:core-ktx:1.8.1'

    // App Search
    def appsearch_version = "1.0.0-alpha04"
    api "androidx.appsearch:appsearch:$appsearch_version"
    // Use kapt instead of annotationProcessor if writing Kotlin classes
    kapt "androidx.appsearch:appsearch-compiler:$appsearch_version"
    api "androidx.appsearch:appsearch-local-storage:$appsearch_version"

    // Google Firebase
    api platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.0')
    api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx'
    api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx'
    api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx'
    api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config-ktx'
    api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf-ktx'
    api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links-ktx'
    api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions-ktx'
    api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx'
    api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-ktx'
    api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-directboot:23.0.0'

    // Google Firebase Auth Google Sign-In
    api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.2.0'

    // Hilt dependency injection
    api "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.40"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.40"

    // Gson for JSON parsing
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.9'

    // Maps SDK
    api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.0.0'

    // Timber
    api 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:5.0.1'

    // Custom Views
    api 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'
}
```

If any extra info is required please ask, my build workflow has been broken for a week :(

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Implement a new version of androidx.core-ktx in your project .

`implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0-alpha03'`

then force the project to use the new version of it.

```
configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy { force 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0-alpha03' }
}
```

Comment: Can you show where place to add your content?

Answer (score -1):

just only remove line

implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'

that should fix the warning